# Why doesn't gtkwave accept my verilog code?

Tags: verilog

I want to display the waveforms of my code on gtkwave, but after I enter these statements in the CMI:

> iverilog -o task_compiled task.v
>
> vvp task_compiled

=> VCD info: dumpfile main.vcd opened for output

> gtkwave task.vcd

=> GTKwave Analyzer ...

```
 error opening .vcd file `task.vcd`
```

I apologize in advance if this comes as a stupid question but i'm seriously tired of
wasting my time with this thing. I just want to do my homework

---

```
timescale 1ns/10ps
module main(A_i, B_i, C_i, Y_o);  
    input A_i, B_i, C_i;
    output Y_o;
    wire w1, w2, w3, w4;
    assign   Y_o = w4 ~& w2;
    assign   w1 = B_i & C_i;
    assign   w2 = w1 | w3;
    assign   w3 = w4 | A_i;
    assign   w4 = A_i ~| w1;
endmodule
module main_tb;         
    reg a1, b1, c1;
    wire y1;
    
    initial begin
    $dumpfile("main.vcd");  
    $dumpvars(0,a1,b1,c1,y1);   
    a1 = 0;         
    b1 = 0;
    # 10 a1 = 1;        
    # 10 b1 = 1;         
    # 10 a1 = 0;        
    # 10 $finish;       
    end
    main m1 (a1, b1, c1, y1);   
endmodule
```

Answer (score 5):

$dumpfile("main.vcd");
versus 
gtkwave task.vcd

...it helps if the correct filename is used.  I just added perror() as an error message to give more information when the VCD loaders fail.  (SVN commit #954)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note also that on newer versions of gtkwave, you can simply doubleclick on an icon for the VCD file from the desktop, explorer, etc.  This works on Linux and OSX. [image: sample icons for save and VCD file]  On Windows (and the others), you can drag the icon into a live session of gtkwave.

Comment: i just noticed the disadvantage of beng a windows user. Unfortunately i cant open it directly.Nevertheless i really appreciate your help from you guys

Comment: If you're using Windows and are forced to use gtkwave by your prof, the latest gtkwave is here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkwave/files/gtkwave-3.3.52-bin-win32/ ...it seems most course web pages I've encountered point to a very backlevel version of the program.

You probably can register VCD as a filetype for gtkwave, but I never attempted to figure out how to do that in Windows as I live predominantly in a Linux environment.

Comment: Also, please give specific feedback on pain and suffering encountered by people in your class as I can add a quick start section to the documentation.  It seems that a lot of the digital design classes are treated as rites of passage where you're thrown the IEEE spec, an assignment, and are told to "figure it out."

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you much, but have you read the [GtkWave documentation](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/gtkwave.pdf)? They talk about compiling using a program called `vermin`, not `iverilog`. Look pages 30 and 78. I've seen no debug option to the `gtkwave` command, so I can't really help much. But such a generic error seems to indicate you're most likely missing something obvious (or otherwise that gtkwave programmers are really bad at reporting errors).

Comment: ive looked into the documentation but again its too cryptic. I have nothing against technical details, but they are completely useless if you are a complete amateur. I actually drew the whole waveforms of the circuit by hand because i couldnt move on. Verilog and gtkwave are supposed to be tools to HELP me with my work, but instead i go under the flood of tedious commands. This is an absolute disgrace not only for the designers of this "tool" but also for my professors who didnt even bother to teach you anything how to use verilog. Still thanks for the tip, mate!

Comment: Giving you a hammer doesn't make you a carpenter. You'll run through the process of trying to learn something and figure out the missing pieces yourself several times throughout your life, so you'd better get used to it. Assuming people are complete amateurs would lead to write gigantic documentation that most people wouldn't read because they'd get scared. That's why some people write real books, to teach more than the big picture. Once you know how the tools work, you actually win time using them. And please, don't be hash with the developers of a free tool, they didn't force you to use it.

Comment: Try to type "gtkwave tutorial" in a search engine or in youtube, you my have more luck.

Comment: i see your point, but i think you have a wrong impression from me. My problem is that i HAVE to use it in my course, of course nobody forces me to use it, but again my critic is perfectly valid. I have used a number of different programming languages and professional tools and i never went through such an unnecessary process of tedious debugging, never. In the forum of my university there was a flood by Hundreds of students that had similiar problems just to install it and run it, while just a tiny minority needed actually  help with for ex. java, C, haskell etc.Lets tell it like it is